# Grabbing Null and blank Columns to a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to grab the count of nulls and blanks of every column in a table and put the results into a table.  I found this but don't know how to push it to a table?  Would also like to add in a Count(distinct fieldname) as well.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(max)
SET @t = N'SELECT '

SELECT @t = @t + 'sum(case when ' + c.name + ' is null or ' + c.name + ' = '''' then 1 else 0 end) "' + c.name + '",
                sum(case when ' + c.name + ' is null then 0 else 1 end) "Non-Null Values for ' + c.name + '",'
                 
FROM sys.columns c 
WHERE c.object_id = object_id('TableName');

SET @t = SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LEN(@t) - 1) + ' FROM TableName;'

EXEC sp_executesql @t
```

**Edit
This provides the results in one row.  Is there a way to do it so each field gets it's own row in a table?

```
FieldName  CountofNullsBlanks
FieldA      0
FieldB      100
```

Comment: Change `SET @t = SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LEN(@t) - 1) + ' FROM TableName;'` to `SET @t = SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LEN(@t) - 1) + ', Count(*) CountOfColumn INTO NewTableName FROM TableName;'` will create named 'NewTableName' and insert all rows into that table. And No need to use distinct because one table cannot have duplicated column name, and no need to use fieldname because of same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(max)
SET @t = N'SELECT '+convert(nvarchar(max),count(*))+' as [Distinct fieldnames],' -- added the distinct

SELECT @t = @t + 'sum(case when ' + c.name + ' is null or ' + c.name + ' = '''' then 1 else 0 end) "' + c.name + '",
                sum(case when ' + c.name + ' is null then 0 else 1 end) "Non-Null Values for ' + c.name + '",'
                 
FROM sys.columns c 
WHERE c.object_id = object_id('YOURTABLE');

SET @t = SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LEN(@t) - 1) + 'into ##a FROM YOURTABLE;' --added the into ##a

EXEC sp_executesql @t
```

Notice the "into ##a" towards the end; This saves the result "table" to a global temp, which will be available until all sessions that accessed it finish. Careful with the name or it might cause conflicts in the database.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there a way to do it so each field name would have it's own row? So the table would have 2 columns FieldName and CountOfNullsBlanks and then it could be populated that way?